Can't use app.component after importing my app vue3
In my vue3 app my entry is: main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import router from './router'
import App from './App.vue'
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
//if I do console.log(app) I have my app correctly initialized
export default app

in a separate file index.js
import app from '../renderer/src/main.js'
console.log(app)
//...rest of code I need to use app.component()

I have this error: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'app' before initialization.
I checked the paths, and they are correct. As I mentioned in the code of main.js, my app is correctly initialized since I can see it with a console.log, but I can't export it correctly. What I want is to be able to use app.component and app.use in a separate file.

This could be XY problem. You get the access to app instance inside vue plugin. That's how plugin system works. Even if it's something beyond the scope of a plugin, you could do the opposite and wrap the code that uses "app" with  a function and call it in main.js. That you're trying to do this outside the source root (src) suggests that you may have a problem related to project organization. Consider explaining your case.

My app contains the core application and modules. I need to import the modules and handle the installation and uninstallation of each module. I'd rather not do this in the main file due to its length, and I want to separate the logic for cleaner code.

To meet your requirement, I suggest creating an index.js within your modules directory exporting a single function that accepts an app instance and registers modules.  You would call this method after initializing the app (passing the created instance). Now, you can register modules in any other app instance, e.g. in tests.

@gitsal The problem is that you import "app" from entry point. It's not just a module, it's an application that is unconditionally initialized with app.mount. It's still unclear why you get this error and what project structure looks like, considering that you have paths to '../renderer/src/main.js'. This could mean that other problems are in code that you didn't show

Thanks for your suggestion @Raeisi, but the app is too complicated to implement what you’ve suggested. My question is whether I can export and import my app and use app.use and app.component the same way we did in Vue 2 (where we used Vue.use and Vue.component without any issues).

@Estus does that mean that normally my import import app from '../renderer/src/main.js' should work fine?

@gitsal No, I can't say this without seeing the project. As I said, this depends on code you didn't show. Normally you shouldn't import one mounted app from another app. This looks like design problem, do I posted an answer.

If you insist on exporting the app, you could export a function that returns the app instance. like export default ()=> app;

@Raeisi this one actually worked for me. Thanks.

That there's a problem with importing app could mean that there's unresolved circular dependency or a problem with the project that is caused by multiple source roots. In a basic scenario there's only one src at project root, anything else requires additional configuration.
This is design problem that isn't exclusive to Vue.
That application instance needs to be reused without calling mount and don't cause circular dependencies could mean that it needs to be extracted to separate module, which could be imported in entry points:
import app from '.../my-app';
app.mount(...);

The code from my-app could be extracted to a function for reusability.
But in Vue a reusable piece of an application is a plugin. It's basically a function that receives application instance and can do anything that is needed with it, including installing other plugins and registering global components, i.e. it can do anything that is usually done between const app = ... and app.mount(...).
In this case it could be:
export default function myAppPlugin(app, options) {
  app.use(router);
  ...
}

In any other entry point that needs to reuse this logic:
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import myAppPlugin from '.../my-app-plugin';
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(myAppPlugin);
app.mount('#app');


I think you can approach it in a different way,
for example:
app.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import router from './router'
import App from './App.vue'
import { initApp, testFn } from "./index.js" // This is your index file
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')

initApp(app);
testFn();


index.js
let app;
export function initApp(_app) {
  app = _app
}

// So you can also use the app in this file
export function testFn() {
  console.log(app)
}

